# why asyncio.run_in_executer does not increase number of tasks in the loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

i am trying to learn python asyncio
i can understand what event loop means ,what coroutine means....
to smaller extent what future and task means
i think that event loop by some how make tasks out of coroutines and some how schedule them in some sort of queue then execute them one by one
my problem is with method run_in_executor
i am trying to understand some python code in order to turn it into c++
in this code as i understand:
 the author make extra one thread >>>>
    `futures.append(executor.submit(do_work, symbol, day, files[symbol]))`
 then this new thread make event loop >>
`csv.append(day, decompress(day, ***fetch_day(symbol, day)***))`

```
`def fetch_day(symbol, day):
    local_data = threading.local()
    loop = getattr(local_data, 'loop', asyncio.new_event_loop())
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    ***loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()***#first event loop
    loop.set_debug(True)`
```

which schedule 24 tasks then >>
    `def create_tasks(symbol, day):

```
    start = 0

    if is_dst(day):
        start = 1

    url_info = {
        'currency': symbol,
        'year': day.year,
        'month': day.month - 1,
        'day': day.day
    }
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get(URL.format(**url_info, hour=i))) for i in range(0, 24)]

    # if is_dst(day):
    #     next_day = day + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    #     url_info = {
    #         'currency': symbol,
    #         'year': next_day.year,
    #         'month': next_day.month - 1,
    #         'day': next_day.day
    #     }
    #     tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get(URL.format(**url_info, hour=0))))
    return tasks`

`   tasks = create_tasks(symbol, day)
    #z=asyncio.Task.all_tasks[0]##############
    ***loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))***
    #y=asyncio.Task.all_tasks[0]##############`
```

each task
    `async def get(url):#each task with total24 of get tasks
        ***loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()***#i dont know if same loop or new one
        buffer = BytesIO()
        id = url[35:].replace('/', " ")
        start = time.time()
        Logger.info("Fetching {0}".format(id))
        for i in range(ATTEMPTS):
            try:
                #z=asyncio.Task.all_tasks[0]##############
                ***res = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: requests.get(url, stream=True))***#this loop if same loop why not increase number of tasks with each get run of the 24 gets>>we should have 48 futures in total`

"here i do not know if it make new loop or use the same loop of the extra thread called 1st thread"
 use a loop to run_in_executer a function making new thread

i wanna know  if it is making new loop
or just use the same loop from extra 1st thread

then if it use the same loop >>>>>
then why the number of handlers of tasks does not increase after running the run_in_executer coroutine

"my understanding is run_in_executer coroutine make new task added to the loop so why it does not increase the number of tasks of the loop

another thought is that there is another set of future separate from loop tasks used only with thread

how can i know at any time the number of futures waiting in the loop?

the code is duka-master from git hub

here is the code:

## main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import sys
import logging
import argparse
from datetime import date, timedelta

#from duka.app import app
#from duka.core import valid_date, set_up_signals
#from duka.core.utils import valid_timeframe, TimeFrame
from app import app
from core import valid_date, set_up_signals
from core.utils import valid_timeframe, TimeFrame
VERSION = '0.2.1'


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='duka', usage='%(prog)s [options]')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version',
                        version='Version: %(prog)s-{version}'.format(version=VERSION))
    parser.add_argument('symbols', metavar='SYMBOLS', type=str, nargs='?',
                        help='symbol list using format EURUSD EURGBP', default=["GBPJPY"])
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--day', type=valid_date, help='specific day format YYYY-MM-DD (default today)',
                        default=date.today() - timedelta(1))
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--startdate', type=valid_date, help='start date format YYYY-MM-DD (default today)')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--enddate', type=valid_date, help='end date format YYYY-MM-DD (default today)')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--thread', type=int, help='number of threads (default 20)', default=5)
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--folder', type=str, help='destination folder (default .)', default='.')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--candle', type=valid_timeframe,
                        help='use candles instead of ticks. Accepted values M1 M2 M5 M10 M15 M30 H1 H4',
                        default=TimeFrame.TICK)
    parser.add_argument('--header', action='store_true', help='include CSV header (default false)', default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.startdate is not None:
        start = args.startdate
    else:
        start = args.day

    if args.enddate is not None:
        end = args.enddate
    else:
        end = args.day

    # Configure logging to show the name of the thread
    # where the log message originates.
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(threadName)10s %(name)18s: %(message)s',
        stream=sys.stderr,
    )
    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    set_up_signals()
    app(args.symbols, start, end, args.thread, args.candle, args.folder, args.header)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## app.py

```
import concurrent
import threading
import time
from collections import deque
from datetime import timedelta, date

#from ..core import decompress, fetch_day, Logger
#from ..core.csv_dumper import CSVDumper
#from ..core.utils import is_debug_mode, TimeFrame
from core import decompress, fetch_day, Logger
from core.csv_dumper import CSVDumper
from core.utils import is_debug_mode, TimeFrame

SATURDAY = 5
day_counter = 0


def days(start, end):
    if start > end:
        return
    end = end + timedelta(days=1)
    today = date.today()
    while start != end:
        if start.weekday() != SATURDAY and start != today:
            yield start
        start = start + timedelta(days=1)


def format_left_time(seconds):
    if seconds < 0:
        return "--:--:--"
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)


def update_progress(done, total, avg_time_per_job, threads):
    progress = 1 if total == 0 else done / total
    progress = int((1.0 if progress > 1.0 else progress) * 100)
    remainder = 100 - progress
    estimation = (avg_time_per_job * (total - done) / threads)
    if not is_debug_mode():
        print('\r[{0}] {1}%  Left : {2}  '.format('#' * progress + '-' * remainder, progress,
                                                  format_left_time(estimation)), end='')


def how_many_days(start, end):
    return sum(1 for _ in days(start, end))


def avg(fetch_times):
    if len(fetch_times) != 0:
        return sum(fetch_times) / len(fetch_times)
    else:
        return -1


def name(symbol, timeframe, start, end):
    ext = ".csv"

    for x in dir(TimeFrame):
        if getattr(TimeFrame, x) == timeframe:
            ts_str = x

    name = symbol + "_" + ts_str + "_" + str(start)

    if start != end:
        name += "_" + str(end)

    return name + ext


def app(symbols, start, end, threads, timeframe, folder, header):
    if start > end:
        return
    lock = threading.Lock()
    global day_counter
    total_days = how_many_days(start, end)

    if total_days == 0:
        return

    last_fetch = deque([], maxlen=5)
    update_progress(day_counter, total_days, -1, threads)

    def do_work(symbol, day, csv):
        global day_counter
        star_time = time.time()
        Logger.info("Fetching day {0}".format(day))
        try:
            csv.append(day, decompress(day, ***fetch_day(symbol, day)***))
        except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR for {0}, {1} Exception : {2}".format(day, symbol, str(e)))
        elapsed_time = time.time() - star_time
        last_fetch.append(elapsed_time)
        with lock:
            day_counter += 1
        Logger.info("Day {0} fetched in {1}s".format(day, elapsed_time))

    futures = []

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:

        files = {symbol: CSVDumper(symbol, timeframe, start, end, folder, header) for symbol in symbols}

        for symbol in symbols:
            for day in days(start, end):
                ***futures.append(executor.submit(do_work, symbol, day, files[symbol]))***#>>>>>>>>>>first extra thread

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            if future.exception() is None:
                update_progress(day_counter, total_days, avg(last_fetch), threads)
            else:
                Logger.error("An error happen when fetching data : ", future.exception())

        Logger.info("Fetching data terminated")
        for file in files.values():
            file.dump()

    update_progress(day_counter, total_days, avg(last_fetch), threads)
```

## fetch.py

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import threading
import time
from functools import reduce
from io import BytesIO, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE

import requests

#from ..core.utils import Logger, is_dst
from core.utils import Logger, is_dst

URL = "https://www.dukascopy.com/datafeed/{currency}/{year}/{month:02d}/{day:02d}/{hour:02d}h_ticks.bi5"
ATTEMPTS = 5


***async def get(url):***#each task with total24 of get tasks
    ***loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()***#i dont know if same loop or new one
    buffer = BytesIO()
    id = url[35:].replace('/', " ")
    start = time.time()
    Logger.info("Fetching {0}".format(id))
    for i in range(ATTEMPTS):
        try:
            #z=asyncio.Task.all_tasks[0]##############
            ***res = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: requests.get(url, stream=True))***#this loop if same loop why not increase number of tasks with each get run of the 24 gets>>we should have 48 futures in total
            if res.status_code == 200:
                for chunk in res.iter_content(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
                    buffer.write(chunk)
                Logger.info("Fetched {0} completed in {1}s".format(id, time.time() - start))
                if len(buffer.getbuffer()) <= 0:
                    Logger.info("Buffer for {0} is empty ".format(id))
                return buffer.getbuffer()
            else:
                Logger.warn("Request to {0} failed with error code : {1} ".format(url, str(res.status_code)))
        except Exception as e:
            Logger.warn("Request {0} failed with exception : {1}".format(id, str(e)))
            time.sleep(0.5 * i)

    raise Exception("Request failed for {0} after ATTEMPTS attempts".format(url))


def create_tasks(symbol, day):

    start = 0

    if is_dst(day):
        start = 1

    url_info = {
        'currency': symbol,
        'year': day.year,
        'month': day.month - 1,
        'day': day.day
    }
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get(URL.format(**url_info, hour=i))) for i in range(0, 24)]

    # if is_dst(day):
    #     next_day = day + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    #     url_info = {
    #         'currency': symbol,
    #         'year': next_day.year,
    #         'month': next_day.month - 1,
    #         'day': next_day.day
    #     }
    #     tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get(URL.format(**url_info, hour=0))))
    return tasks


def fetch_day(symbol, day):
    local_data = threading.local()
    loop = getattr(local_data, 'loop', asyncio.new_event_loop())
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    ***loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()***#first event loop
    loop.set_debug(True)
    tasks = create_tasks(symbol, day)
    #z=asyncio.Task.all_tasks[0]##############
    ***loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))***
    #y=asyncio.Task.all_tasks[0]##############
    def add(acc, task):
        acc.write(task.result())
        return acc

    return reduce(add, tasks, BytesIO()).getbuffer()
```

## other code:

in this code run_in_thread make futures in the block list
so in the previous code where are these tasks???????????

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import sys
import time


def blocks(n):
    log = logging.getLogger('blocks({})'.format(n))
    log.info('running')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    log.info('done')
    return n ** 2


async def run_blocking_tasks(executor):
    log = logging.getLogger('run_blocking_tasks')
    log.info('starting')

    log.info('creating executor tasks')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    blocking_tasks = [
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocks, i)
        for i in range(6)
    ]
    log.info('waiting for executor tasks')
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(blocking_tasks)
    results = [t.result() for t in completed]
    log.info('results: {!r}'.format(results))

    log.info('exiting')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Configure logging to show the name of the thread
    # where the log message originates.
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(threadName)10s %(name)18s: %(message)s',
        stream=sys.stderr,
    )

    # Create a limited thread pool.
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
        max_workers=3,
    )

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(
            run_blocking_tasks(executor)
        )
    finally:
        event_loop.close()
```

`

Comment: What is the question? Instead of adding all your code, just add the part relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` is not `asyncio` compatible.  Use [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout

async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def main(loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://python.org')
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply...i am trying to understand what happens when new thread is created from loop and where does its future reside?.....i use visual studio and when i debug and add watch for loop  i find under _ready all 24 tasks but as new threads are made and thus new futures are created the _ready list never increase its handlers>>>>>>>this is what i m looking for....thanks again

Comment: Please supply a **short** simple piece of code that does just that in order to help you.